# Angular renderer.setStyle() on renderer2 isn't working

Tags: angular, typescript, htmlelements, angular-renderer2

i'm learning Angular, and i have an issue with renderer2, it seems the get is working fine and he gets to the function styleChoice with the right informations but the setStyle isn't working with the ngInit. I tried to await the function but it did not work neither.

Thank you guys for your help.

constructor()

```
constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig, private element: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
      this.gateau = "Gateau au yaourt";
      this.tarteAuPomme = "TarteAuPomme"
      this.gateauMariage = "gateauMariage"
      this.chocolatsFruitRouge = "chocolatsFruitRouge"
      config.interval = 0;
      config.wrap = true;
      config.keyboard = true;
      config.animation = true;
      config.showNavigationIndicators = false;
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.choix = params['choix'];
    });
```

ngOnInit()

```
  ngOnInit(){
    switch(this.choix){
      case 'gateau':{
        this.styleChoice(document.getElementById('gateau'));
        break;
      }
      case 'tarteAuPomme':{
        this.styleChoice(document.getElementById('tarteAuPomme'));
        break;
      }
      case 'gateauMariage':{
        this.styleChoice(document.getElementById('gateauMariage'));
        break;
      }
      case 'chocolatsFruitRouge':{
        this.styleChoice(document.getElementById('chocolatsFruitRouge'));
        break;
      }
    }
```

styleChoice()

```
styleChoice(element:HTMLElement){
    //this.clean();
    console.log(element)
      this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'boxShadow', "0px 0px 3px 20px rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
      this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'background', "rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
      this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'borderRadius', "20px");
    switch(element.id){
      case "gateau" :{
        this.renderer.setProperty(document.getElementById('choix-selection-validation-text'), 'innerHTML', this.gateau)
        break
      }
      case "tarteAuPomme" :{
        this.renderer.setProperty(document.getElementById('choix-selection-validation-text'), 'innerHTML', this.tarteAuPomme)
        break
      }
      case "gateauMariage" :{
        this.renderer.setProperty(document.getElementById('choix-selection-validation-text'), 'innerHTML', this.gateauMariage)
        break
      }
      case "chocolatsFruitRouge" :{
        this.renderer.setProperty(document.getElementById('choix-selection-validation-text'), 'innerHTML', this.chocolatsFruitRouge)
        break
      }
    }

  }
```

EDIT

```
  @ViewChild('choiceRef') choiceRef: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('choiceRef2') choiceRef2: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('choiceRef3') choiceRef3: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('choiceRef4') choiceRef4: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    switch(this.choix){
      case 'gateau':{
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef3.nativeElement, 'boxShadow', "0px 0px 3px 20px rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef3.nativeElement, 'background', "rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef3.nativeElement, 'borderRadius', "20px");
        break;
      }
      case 'tarteAuPomme':{
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef2.nativeElement, 'boxShadow', "0px 0px 3px 20px rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef2.nativeElement, 'background', "rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef2.nativeElement, 'borderRadius', "20px");
        break;
      }
      case 'gateauMariage':{
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef.nativeElement, 'boxShadow', "0px 0px 3px 20px rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef.nativeElement, 'background', "rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef.nativeElement, 'borderRadius', "20px");
        break;
      }
      case 'chocolatsFruitRouge':{
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef4.nativeElement, 'boxShadow', "0px 0px 3px 20px rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef4.nativeElement, 'background', "rgba(243, 65, 65, 0.8)");
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.choiceRef4.nativeElement, 'borderRadius', "20px");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use ViewChild or ViewChildren decorators?

Comment: Can you check my edit ? it's working but i'm not sure that's the most optimize solution. Also, why it was not working, i tried to await the function but nothind worked.